# Associate existing SSL certificate to IIS Website

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5

Here's my scenario:
* I have a certificate installed on my server (Windows Server 2008 R2, with IIS 7.5)
* I create a new HTTPS binding via PowerShell command (New-WebBinding), but I have no way here to associate this to the certificate I have (for which I do have the Thumbprint)

Any ideas on how I can go about making this association. In the attached screenshot, this can be done in the GUI simply by editing the HTTPS binding and selecting it from the drop-down, though haven't seen a good example to do this via PowerShell or Command Line.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Get-WebBinding` cmdlet to retrieve the binding of your website and set the certificate using the `AddSslCertificate` method:

```
$httpsBinding = Get-WebBinding -Name "YourWebSiteName" -Protocol "https"
$httpsBinding.AddSslCertificate('SSL_HASH_STRING', "my")
```

Comment: Done. Also, this didn't work for me on Windows Server 2012 / IIS 8, though it wasn't as much a concern there. Did you try this in Server 2012? Any alternate script there?

Comment: Not hundret percent sure but I use this script in an installer which also runs on Server 2012. Should work?

Comment: This throws the error "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated" in powershell.